# Looking for a script or something to generate the numbers 1.1.1.1 to 255.255.255.255

Tags: ip

Yes thats right, I am looking for a script or anything that can generate an ip address
list from 1.1.1.1 to 255.255.255.255. Even if its something like cat or grep that generates
the numbers 1.1.1.1 to 255.255.255.255. Thanks!
I found 1 python script but it seems to not work very well.

Comment: Do you want all of the ip addresses without zeros? or all of the ip addresses after 1.1.1.1? Should 127.0.0.1 be in the list?

Comment: Every ip inbetween 1.1.1.1 and 255.255.255.255.

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted this..

Comment: Unfortunately, people are allowed to downvote without leaving a comment. Anyway, you realize you're asking for around four billion numbers, right? And you haven't answered genisage's questions.

Comment: I know, I need every single number. All IPs after 1.1.1.1 .

Comment: Seems insane. If you want it saved to a file it would be at least 50 gigs. What do you want them for?

Comment: I just want to experiment with them. The size will be: 50.0488Gb

Comment: In what sense? Are you going to pipe them to another process? Do you want them in a file? Do you know how to compile a C program?

Comment: Yeah putting them in a .txt file is nice. Yes I can compile a c script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#if UINT_MAX != 4294967295
#error Assumes 32-bit ints for stopping condition.
#endif

int main() {
  unsigned n = 0x01010101;
  for ( ; n != 0; ++n)
    printf("%d.%d.%d.%d\n", n>>24, (n>>16)&0xff, (n>>8)&0xff, n&0xff);
  return 0;
}
```

Just redirect standard output to a file and leave it running for ... I don't know how long.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you're looking for a string format?

```
int a,b,c,d;
char address[16];
char e[4],f[4],g[4],h[4];
for(a=1;a<=255;a++)
{
    for(b=1;b<=255;b++)
    {
        for(c=1;c<=255;c++)
        {
            for(d=1;d<=255;d++)
            {
                //You'll want to clear e,f,g, and h here, as well as null-terminating
                //them once they've been cast and copied. 
                strcpy(e,((char)(a)));//Cast your rolling 'int's to 'char's
                strcpy(f,((char)(b)));
                strcpy(g,((char)(c)));
                strcpy(h,((char)(d)));
                strcpy(address,"\0");//Clear your string before constructing
                strcat(address,e);
                strcat(address,'.');//Might need double-quotes(".")
                strcat(address,f);    
                strcat(address,'.');
                strcat(address,g);
                strcat(address,'.');
                strcat(address,h);
                strcat(address,'\0');
                //Do whatever you need to do here. (Copy to array or whatever)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Besides being vastly over-complicated, this does not generate any IP's with zeros in them, such as `123.0.12.1`

Comment: @ooga, Yes, I see that, but I was working on this before that requirement was clarified... Modifying for that requirement would only make it even more "over-complicated".